# Use of ThreadLocals in a ForkJoinPool

Tags: java, thread-local, fork-join

I'm working with an external library that uses a `ThreadLocal` object to keep track of state. Is this safe for use with a work-stealing executor such as `ForkJoinPool`?

Specifically, if a task is blocked and the work stealing algorithm picks up a new task, will that new task and the previous task end up sharing the `ThreadLocal` object, thereby corrupting it and making it unusable to record state? And if so, what's the best way to proceed, besides using a non-work-stealing executor like the old-school fixed `ThreadPoolExecutor`?

Comment: The question isn't really *is it safe* as much as *what kind of state* and *how do you get it outside of the task*?

Comment: What does ThreadLocal have to do with Tasks and your threads? F/J has its own threads. You cannot mix your threads with F/J threads, except for the submitting thread which can be used by F/J as a work thread. If this is a concern then no, using ThreadLocal is not safe. Without more info, I cannot answer your question.

Comment: In the case of a fixed ThreadPoolExecutor, a submitted task can store state information in a `ThreadLocal` and no other tasks will overwrite it, since there's a 1 to 1 mapping between thread and task in that case.

Comment: What you're doing is not a good design for F/J. Look at the code in F/J, it's a nightmare. You cannot use ThreadLocal storage for yourself in F/J. As above, F/J uses your submitting thread as a worker which can produce undesirable results. http://coopsoft.com/ar/Calamity2Article.html#submission